# Why can't the protocol of an URL object be changed for non-http(s) URLs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, url

In JavaScript, there seems to be some restrictions when changing the protocol of a given URL when using the `URL` object. However, I can't find where this behaviour is documented ([`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL), [`URL.prototype.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/protocol)) or why it would be intended for it to work like that.

Can anyone shine some light on this?

EDIT: The behaviour seems to be inconsistent across JS runtimes. Firefox, Node and Deno all "refuse" to change the protocol, but Chrome, Safari and Bun all "comply" with the change…

```js
const url1 = new URL('http://example.com')
console.log(url1.protocol) // http:
url1.protocol = 'https:'
console.log(url1.protocol) // https:

const url2 = new URL('webcal://example.com')
console.log(url2.protocol) // webcal:
url2.protocol = 'https:'
console.log(url2.protocol) // webcal:, but should be https:
```

Comment: Looks like it works, at least in Chrome

Comment: security, mostly. If you want to use URLs that trigger applications, that protocol needs to have a handler built into the browser. Otherwise it's just a meaningless word. Chrome supports webcal: because Google obviously supports their own protocols.

Comment: @mplungjan That is very interesting, as both Firefox and Node return `webcal:` instead of `https:`…

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans My use-case is converting a `webcal:` URL to `https:` so that it can be fetched. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: That's not what you're showing though, you're showing domain URLs. Using https for an actual ics file will work perfectly fine, and will download as a plain text file, as long as you just make a new URL. Don't fudge the `protocol` property, just create a new URL object based on the old URL as string.

Comment: I stumbled on this whilst using the URL object to modify the protocol and path of my urls (in the process of downloading ICSs) and noticed this surprising behaviour. I then distilled it into this simple example to look at the behaviour in different runtimes, and am now very surprised at the inconsistencies.

Comment: Not answering your question, but a simple workaround: `urlString.replace(/^.*?(?=:)/, "https")`

Comment: I already have a fix, I am just trying to find where this behaviour is documented or why there are such inconsistencies

Comment: It may have something to do with changing the `origin` from an "opaque origin" to one that is not opaque. See [the spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#origin). That's a guess as to motives though; [the spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-protocol) says nothing about that issue when documenting the `protocol` setter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [documented for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlprotocol):

> The [WHATWG URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) considers a handful of URL protocol schemes to
> be *special* in terms of how they are parsed and serialized. When a
> URL is parsed using one of these special protocols, **the
> `url.protocol` property may be changed to another special protocol but
> cannot be changed to a non-special protocol, and vice versa.**
>
> For instance, changing from `http` to `https` works: […]
>
> However, changing from `http` to a hypothetical `fish` protocol does not
> because the new protocol is not special. […]
>
> Likewise, changing from a non-special protocol to a special protocol
> is also not permitted: […]
>
> According to the WHATWG URL Standard, special protocol schemes are
> `ftp`, `file`, `http`, `https`, `ws`, and `wss`.

<sup>(emphasis and ellipsis mine)</sup>

Your `webcal` protocol is not in that list, so you cannot change it to `https`.

The intention of distinguishing [special](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#is-special) from non-special URLs appears to be that their hostname should be parsed differently, e.g. requiring valid domain names. That makes switching protocols a hazard if the hostname of the existing URL does not satisfy the requirements of the new protocol.

For Node.js, this is implemented by the C++ [Ada URL library](https://github.com/ada-url/ada). Deno uses the Rust [urlpattern crate](https://github.com/denoland/rust-urlpattern). Firefox already [changed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1347459) their implementation to comply with the spec, Chrome [followed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1416018) just recently and will release this with M118. The Webkit (Safari, Bun) [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=229427) is still open.

Still, this is bonkers, and there is a [specification issue opened in 2021](https://github.com/whatwg/url/issues/674) to allow this. There also might be web compatibility issues with this restriction, so they may have to adjust the spec instead. However, it appears that the current plan is to follow through with it, and instead add a constructor for creating a new `URL` from parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed response! I will award the bounty as soon as StackOverflow allows me to